# Solution of $y''-x^2y=0$ comes out by series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I tried to solve the differential equation $y''(x)-x^2y(x)=0$ by series solution, but but it doesn't seem right. My terms become zero when they depend on $a_2$ and $a_3$ and I can't find the general form of the recurrence relations. Does anyone know the solution?

With $y=\sum_0a_nx^n$ and $y''=\sum_2a_nn(n-1)x^{(n-2)}$

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_2a_nn(n-1)x^{(n-2)}-\sum_0a_nx^{n+2}=0 \\
\sum_{-2}a_{n+4}(n+4)(n+3)x^{(n+2)}-\sum_0a_nx^{n+2}=0 \\
2a_2+6a_3x+\sum_{0}[a_{n+4}(n+4)(n+3)-a_n]x^{n+2}=0
\end{eqnarray}

then,

\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n+4}=\frac{a_n}{(n+4)(n+3)}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Mind to show us what you have tried so we can know what has gone wrong?

Comment: Please edit the above into the question, comments are for discussions about the post, not for post contents. Btw., it looks right what you got and observed.

Comment: For one thing, where is your $a_0$ and $a_1$?  They are in the defining series but you have no later mention of them.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your observation, we first note that $a_2 = a_3 = 0$. Also, if we write $n = 4q+r$ for some $q\geq 0$ and $r\in\{0,1,2,3,\}$, then for $q \geq 1$ we get

$$ a_{4q+r} = \frac{a_{4(q-1)+4}}{(4q+r)(4q+r-1)} = \frac{a_r}{\prod_{k=1}^{q} (4k+r)(4k+r-1)}, $$

where the empty product is regarded as $1$. So,

- If $r = 0$, then
  $$ a_{4q} = \frac{a_0}{\prod_{k=1}^{q} (4k)(4k-1)} = \frac{a_0}{16^q} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{3}{4})} $$
- If $r = 1$, then
  $$ a_{4q+1} = \frac{a_r}{\prod_{k=1}^{q} (4k+1)(4k)} = \frac{a_1}{16^q} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{5}{4})}. $$
- If $r= 2$ or $r=3$, then we can show that $a_{4q+r} = 0$ for all $q \geq $ by the induction on $q$.

Therefore the general solution is given by

\begin{align*}
y(x)
&= a_0 \Gamma(\tfrac{3}{4}) \sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{3}{4})} \biggl( \frac{x}{2} \biggr)^{4q} + 2 a_1 \Gamma(\tfrac{5}{4}) \sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{5}{4})} \biggl( \frac{x}{2} \biggr)^{4q+1} \tag{*}
\end{align*}

Those two particular solutions appearing in $\text{(*)}$ can also be written in terms of the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1):

\begin{gather*}
\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{3}{4})} \biggl( \frac{x}{2} \biggr)^{4q}
= \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right), \\
\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q!\Gamma(q+\frac{5}{4})} \biggl( \frac{x}{2} \biggr)^{4q+1}
= \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right).
\end{gather*}