# How to get to $\psi=Ae^{\xi^2/2}+Be^{-\xi^2/2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I saw proof that this is the solution, but not how to find it. Just in the Eisberg's book assuming thar for

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\xi^2\psi
\end{equation}

Will have:

\begin{equation}
\psi=Ae^{\xi^2/2}+Be^{-\xi^2/2}
\end{equation}

Comment: That function doesn't satisfy the ODE. Are you sure you've read everything correctly? And could you be more specific with the reference? Which book is that, and what page?

Comment: @HansLundmark Fudamentals of Modern Physics, Robert Martin Eisberg. At chapter 8(Solutions of Schrodinger's equation), section 6 (The simple Harmonic Oscillator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the book, and found that the author is proposing that form

$$ A e^{\xi^2/2} + B e^{-\xi^2/2} $$

merely as an *asymptotic formula* as $\left|\xi\right|\to\infty$. Indeed, a precise form of the general solution is

$$ \psi(\xi) = A \sqrt{\xi}\, I_{-1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right) + B \sqrt{\xi} \, I_{1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right), $$

where $I_{\nu}$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). This can be obtained via series solution method, as illustrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3919117/9340).

Also note that this can also be used to justify the proposed asymptotic formula, since

\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{\xi}\, I_{-1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right) + \sqrt{\xi} \, I_{1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right)
\sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\smash[b]{\xi}}} \, e^{\xi^2/2}, \\
\sqrt{\xi}\, I_{-1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right) - \sqrt{\xi} \, I_{1/4} \left(\xi^2/2\right)
\sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi\smash[b]{\xi}}} \, e^{-\xi^2/2}
\end{gather*}

holds as $\xi \to \infty$.